# Try, Except is not giving required result in django serializers create method. the getobject statements gives required result if put is outside try:

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-queryset

```
class BeneficiarySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Beneficiary
        fields ='__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            available = Beneficiary.objects.get(coupon_code=validated_data['coupan_code'])
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The provided coupon code is already utilized")
        except:
            return super().create(validated_data)


class Coupon(models.Model):
    sl_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    c_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.c_code


class Beneficiary(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    coupon_code = models.ForeignKey(Coupon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

purpose is to issue a coupon to only one person, if the same coupon code is issued to another in that case Serializers should raise and error that the key is issued to someone.
if i put the code in try and except every time the verification fails, the same coupon code is allotted to many, if use objects.get outside try: statement is return result is found. please let me know if i am not using try: except in proper way or any other way to deal with this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is no matter what that code is going to raise an exception and the call to `super` is going to occur any way. If there is no matching `Beneficiary` for your query a `DoesNotExist` exception will be raised by the `get` method, if it does you yourself raise an exception. Immediately you catch them and call `super`.

Moving further you don't even need exceptions for this simple purpose, neither should you perform this validation in the `create` method! You should write a [`validate_<field>` method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) and make an [`exists` query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#exists) there:

```
class BeneficiarySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Beneficiary
        fields ='__all__'
    
    def validate_coupon_code(self, value):
        if Beneficiary.objects.filter(coupon_code=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The provided coupon code is already utilized")
        return value
```